# How do I move Finder icon location in the dock?

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, dock

The Finder icon on the dock seems to be locked to be the first one. I would like to have a few other application icons to the left of the Finder icon, but click-and-drag doesn't work for it.

What the dock looks like:
[image: Screenshot of dock.]
Finder, Launchpad, Mission Control, and then Chrome

Order of icons that I want instead:
Launchpad, Mission Control, Chrome, and then Finder

I'm running macOS High Sierra on a Mac Mini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2078361?tstart=0) from almost 10 years ago on making a duplicate icon you can move, but the original stays. As far as I can tell there is not way to move the Finder or Trash icons from their position in the dock.

Comment: I chose your post as my accepted answer as there simply doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want. Shame. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, I accidently delete Finder from dock and don't know how to restore them, maybe in Mojave it is possible now)

Comment: This is a clear violation of the `Freedom of Position` by Apple & we must condemn it :)

Comment: this is just stupid Apple, come on...

Answer (score 1):

The Finder and Trash applications are the only 2 apps that cannot have their position moved in the dock or be removed from the dock.